# How to prove the sequence is cauchy's

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I know the def. Of cauchy sequences but I don't know how to prove it can you help me .

For any  ${n}\in\mathbb{N}$ put ${s_n}={1}+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}$

a) Show that the sequence $(s_n)_{{n}\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy sequence according to the standard metric on $\mathbb Q$

b) For any ${q}\in\mathbb{N}$ show that ${q}!{s}_{q}\mathrm{\in}\mathbb{Z}$ and
$
{0}<q!({e}-{s}_{q})<1$
Where:
$
{e}\mathrm{{=}}\mathop{\sum}\limits_{{n}\mathrm{{=}}{0}}\limits^{\mathrm{\infty}}{\frac{1}{n\mathrm{!}}}
$

C)show that $e$ irrational number and $\mathbb Q$ is not complete set.

I can write the definition of a Cauchy sequence but I don't know to use it to have an convincing answer.
$(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence that means 
$
\mathrm{\forall}\mathrm{\varepsilon}\mathrm{>}{0}{\mathrm{,}}\mathrm{\exists}{n}_{0}\mathrm{\in}{N}{\mathrm{,}}\mathrm{\forall}{n}{\mathrm{,}}{m}\mathrm{{>}}{n}_{0}\hspace{0.33em}{d}{\mathrm{(}}{x}_n\mathrm{,}x_m{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{<}}\mathrm{\varepsilon}
$
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, compare this sequence to $t_n = 1 + \frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + ... + \frac{1}{n^2}$. We know by p-test ${t_n}$ converges so can you see why your sequence ${s_n}$ converges?

Comment: Part b. is pretty clear if you subtract off the common terms.

Comment: Are you aware that this sequence converges (in $\mathbb R$, not in $\mathbb Q$) to $e$? All convergent sequences are Cauchy.

Comment: Assume e is rational then use b. Therefore, we have a cauchy sequence which does not converge in Q. Hence, it is not complete.

Comment: @YunusSyed thanks a lot for answering me but can you explain the second part (b)

Comment: $e - s_q = \frac{1}{(q+1)!} + \frac{1}{(q+2)!} + ... < \frac{1}{(q+1)!} * (1 + \frac{1}{q+1} + \frac{1}{(q+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(q+1)^3} + ... ) = \frac{1}{q * q!} < \frac{1}{q!}$. Now multiply both sides by $q!$.

Comment: @YunusSyed i am sorry i didn't get it why the difference between them is like that .

Comment: Write out the sum for e and write out $s_q$ on top of one another on paper

Comment: Can you be more specific for the e irrational number ?

Answer (score 1):

For part (a), you should get (for $m \le n$ and $m, n > N$),
$$
|s_m - s_n| = \sum_{i=m+1}^n \frac{1}{i!}
$$
Now one thing you could do is notice that $\frac{1}{i!} < \frac{1}{i(i-1)} = \frac{1}{i-1} - \frac{1}{i}$. So that gives you
$$
|s_m - s_n| < \sum_{i=m+1}^n \left(\frac{1}{i-1} - \frac{1}{i}\right)
$$
Now this sum is more manageable, if you write it out you will see that most of the terms cancel and you are left with $\frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{n}$. And so you have
$$
|s_m - s_n| < \left|\frac1m - \frac1n\right| < \frac{2}{N}
$$
and so that should give you the ability to pick $N$ depending on $\epsilon$ so that $|s_m - s_n| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer can you explain to me how did we get $ \frac{2}{N} $